# typescript 2.3.4 extending anonymous classes from constructor functions

Tags: class, typescript, extends, anonymous-class, typescript2.3

Essentially, I'm asking why this does not compile:

```
interface Constructor<T> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function ConstructorFactory<T>(t: T) {
  return t as any as Constructor<T>; // pretend we build a new class surrounding t somehow
}

class A extends ConstructorFactory({a: 11}) {

}

function AFactory<T>(t: T) {
  return class AnonymousA extends ConstructorFactory(t) {

  };
}
```

([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Constructor%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20ConstructorFactory%3CT%3E(t%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20t%20as%20any%20as%20Constructor%3CT%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20pretend%20we%20build%20a%20new%20class%20surrounding%20t%20somehow%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20ConstructorFactory(%7Ba%3A%2011%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20AFactory%3CT%3E(t%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20class%20AnonymousA%20extends%20ConstructorFactory(t)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D))

The error is the line with `AnonymousA` and says:

```
Base constructor return type 'T' is not a class or interface type.
```

The main thing I haven't been able to grasp is why I am able to define `class A` ok, but not `AnonymousA`. The generated javascript looks pretty similar for both, so I'm pretty sure this is either a bug, a subtle difference between anonymous classes and regular classes, or something I haven't learned about types. My bet is on the third option?

For context, this came from trying to use immutablejs records as classes. There is a lot of posts about this not working, but I haven't found anyone explain what I think is maybe a simpler example?

Also, I just wrote `ConstructorFactory` as an sketch quickly, I am aware that it's not actually returning a `Constructor<T>`. But I'm pretty sure typescript see's it as the right type.

Thanks for any help! Sorry if it's a duplicate question.